Is it possible to use newer versions of commons-io for older Android devices?
The latest version of Apache Commons IO for Android is 2.13.0. However, I have been using 2.5 for many years:
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

This is because I found commons-io 2.6 would crash the app at least on Android 4.2, and possibly other older versions of Android.
I updated commons-io to 2.13.0 to give it a short:
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.13.0'

Unfortunately, it crashes the app on at least Android 5.1, and 7.1 devices. It is always NoClassDefFoundError:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:3104)

The code responsible for it is:
IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

It works flawlessly on newer versions of Android (e.g., Android 9, 10...).
Could anyone offer a tip on possible remedies for this?
Update[2024-04-25]
The above problem has been resolved by desugaring as suggested by Seigei in his comments. However, the following crash occurs even after desugaring:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;
    at org.apache.commons.io.file.PathUtils.<clinit>(PathUtils.java:151)
    at org.apache.commons.io.build.AbstractStreamBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractStreamBuilder.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder(UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:2644) 

I have no choice but to go back to commons-io:commons-io:2.5 for now.

This might be because "Version 2.7 and up requires Java 8 or above" (Apache Commons IO docs) and Android 8 is the first version with native support for Java 8

Thank you for the tip. Do you have any tips on possible ways to remedy this?

Does this answer your question? Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?

Basically you need to enable "Java 8+ API desugaring support" by following instructions from this doc: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#library-desugaring

I am using jbr-17 which is Java 17? The gradle version is 8.4. minSdkVersion is 19. I do not have any compilation issues. I will give desugaring a shot

@SergeiKozelko I tried desugaring by adding coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled and  coreLibraryDesugaring("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4") and it works. Thank you again. Could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept?
